# Indexing an SQL table by datetime that is scaling

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, query-optimization, where-clause

I have a large table that gets anywhere from 1-3 new entries per minute. I need to be able to find records at specific times which I can do by using a `SELECT` statement but it's incredibly slow. Lets say the table looks like this:

```
Device |     Date-Time     | Data |
-----------------------------------
1      | 2020-01-01 08:00  | 325
2      | 2020-01-01 08:01  | 384
1      | 2020-01-01 08:01  | 175
3      | 2020-01-01 08:01  | 8435
7      | 2020-01-01 08:02  | 784
.
.
.
```

I'm trying to get data like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE Date-Time = '2020-01-01 08:00' AND Device = '1'
```

I also need to get data like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE Date-Time > '2020-01-01 08:00' Date-Time < '2020-01-10 08:00' AND Device = '1'
```

But I don't know what the `Date-Time` will be until requested. In this case, I will have to search the entire table for these times. Can I index the start of the day so I know where dates are?

Is there a way to index this table in order to dramatically decrease the queries? Or is there a better way to achieve this?

I have tried indexing the `Date-Time` column but I did not decrease the query time at all.

Comment: What is the clustered index on this table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE date_time = '2020-01-01 08:00' AND device = 1
```

You want an index on `mytable(date_time, device)`. This matches the columns that come into play in the `WHERE` clause, so the database should be able to lookup the matching rows efficiently.

Note that I removed the single quotes around the literal value given to `device`: if this is an integer, as it looks like, then it should be treated as such.

The ordering of the column in the index matters; generally, you want the most restrictive column first - from the description of your question, this would probably be `date_time`, hence the above suggestion. You might want to try the other way around as well (so: `mytable(device, date_time)`).

Another thing to keep in mind from performance perspective: you should probably enumerate the columns you want in the `SELECT` clause; if you just want a few additional columns, then it can be useful to add them to the index as well; this gives you a *covering* index, that the database can use to execute the whole query without even looking back at the data.

Say:

```
SELECT date_time, device, col1, col2
FROM mytable
WHERE date_time = '2020-01-01 08:00' AND device = 1
```

Then consider:

```
mytable(date_time, device, col1, col2)
```

Or:

```
mytable(device, date_time, col1, col2)
```

Comment: I should have been more clear, I'll make an edit. I also need to get data between two date-times but I don't know what those times are going to be until requested. Can I index in a way where I know where the start of the day is to speed up queries?

Comment: @GreenSaber: yes, this would still benefit an index (maybe you want to put `device` first, as explained in my answer).

Comment: Ok thank you, if I index at `2020-01-01 08:00` would it increase queries for, lets say, `2020-01-01 08:01`?

Comment: @GreenSaber: there seems to be a misonception here. You don't index "at" a specific date. You create an index on a whole column (or a set of columns): `create index myindex on mytable(date_time, device)`.

Comment: Ok after playing around with it I understand how this works. Your solution worked, thank you! Now, if I want to include many columns in the index, is it better practice to have multiple indexes with few columns or one index with multiple colums?

Comment: Also, if records are being inserted every minute, will I need to update or remake the indexes?

Comment: @GreenSaber: no. The database handles that for you under the hood. From time to time, you might want to [update the statistics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/update-statistics-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Answer (score 0):

You can use TimeInMilliseconds as new column and populate it with milliseconds from the year 1970 and create Index on this column. TimeInMilliseconds will always be unique number and it will help the index to search queries faster.